# GCM User Notifications: Missing "registration_ids" field

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Our project has been whitelisted for testing the the new GCM [User Notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html) API that allows grouping Registration IDs to a single "notification key" that can then be used to send messages to all devices owned by the user.

However, when I send a request like this:

```
POST /gcm/send
Authorization: key=…
Content-Type: application/json

{"notification_key": "…",
 "data": {…}
}
```

I get an error response:

```
400 Bad Request

Missing "registration_ids" field
```

Sending a message using the `registration_ids` field instead of the `notification_key` fixes the problem (and the messages get delivered), but the whole point of using the User Notifications API was to use the `notification_key` instead of the `registration_ids`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html):

> **`registration_ids`**:
>   […] A request must include a recipient—this can be either a registration ID, an array of registration IDs, or a notification_key. Required.
>
> **`notification_key`**:
>   A string that maps a single user to multiple registration IDs associated with that user. This allows a 3rd-party server to send a single message to multiple app instances (typically on multiple devices) owned by a single user. A 3rd-party server can use notification_key as the target for a message instead of an individual registration ID (or array of registration IDs). […] Optional.

The above example uses the HTTP connection server at `https://android.googleapis.com`.

So far I tried:

- including an empty array for `registration_ids`, doesn't help
- sending the `notification_key` value as a registration ID in the `registration_ids` field, doesn't work either
- setting the `project_id` header to our Project Number (as required when creating the `notification_key`), still no luck
- using CCS (XMPP) instead of HTTP to communicate with the GCM API server, but unfortunately [the IP is blocked on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18681096/252239)
- including both `notification_key` and `notification_key_name` in the request, doesn't help

**UPDATE:** As per suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-gcm/Ck770zjnenM/NnNxnd_SztMJ), I also tried posting the payload to `/gcm/notification`, with the `"operation": "send"` property included in the JSON request payload. Still no help. Now I get:

```
{"error":"Missing \"registration_ids\" field"}
```

Same thing, only this time it is sent back JSON-encoded.

Comment: `registration_ids` are something you get once the device gets registered with GCM. You have to store this id into your database first, and then use this to send the notifications

Comment: @SunilMishra I can use the `registration_ids` to generate a `notification_key` and then I should be able to use the `notification_key` *instead of the* `registration_ids`.

Comment: Have you tried including both `notification_key` and `notification_key_name` in the request?

Comment: @Eran I have now tried just that (including both the key and the key name), and I get the same error as before, missing `registration_ids` field.

Comment: Do you have any news? Did you manage to do it? We also have a similar problem.

Comment: @tasomaniac nope, we ended up just keeping the Registration IDs in the DB and not using the Notifications API.

Comment: Yeah we also tried to implement it but we gave up.

Comment: How can I send a message to multiple `registration_ids` in IOS ? `registration_ids` and to is not working for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation is buggy, you have to use this request:

```
curl -vvv -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "project_id: <YOUR-PROJECT-ID>" --header "Authorization: key=<YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET-KEY>" --data @- "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" << EOF
{ 
   "to": "<NOTIFICATION-ID>",
   "data": {},
}
EOF
```

please see my blog post https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/d7df385b0ff4 for more details

Comment: You are ABSOLUTLY RIGHT. I changed from "notification_key" to "to" and it works. The documentation is really buggy!

Comment: How do I upvote @Jacek Marchwicki a few more times?!  I will also note that I had to use my "Project Number" not my "Project ID" in the header

Comment: It is ridiculous that the GCM documentation can be this wrong! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean project number @xbakesx? I only see project id and project name (the ID is a number though)

Comment: I still get a 500 Internal Server Error from this.

Comment: Does that mean you found the Project Number?  On the main page of your project https://console.developers.google.com/project/{Project ID} at the top of the content section (for me anyway) it says Project ID: {word}-{word}-{number} and right next to that it says Project Number: {very long number}

Comment: How can I send a message to multiple registration_ids ?
`registration_ids` and `to` is not working for me. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Have you got project_id for your project. 
    If yes then have you included same at proper place.
```

Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) out ..

Comment: The Project ID is required for upstream messages. For downstream (Server -> GCM -> Android), GCM accepts an API Key (as part of the "Authorization" header), which is then used to authenticate the server and connect it to the corresponding Project.

Comment: project_id is required by GCM to wonder which application needs attention... Once GCM locates desired project then it moves ahead by taking device_id of user to put notification.

Comment: No, GCM can identify the request based on the API key alone, and the `device_id` should not be required by the User Notifications API. Please read my question carefully. Besides, I tried including the Project ID, just in case. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this issue "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized".
And, I resolved the issue by replacing the API Key with the Browser Key.

Use a browser key if your application is running on a client.

Please refer to the following link:
https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys