# GCM java server example

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Does anyone have a link to GCM java 3rd Party Server example? I can't understand how to implement it. In http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html, I could not find a complete example.

Comment: GCM is deprecated. Use https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Answer (score 35):

The easiest way is to use `gcm-server.jar` (which you can get from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/)).

Then the code you'll need to send a GCM message will look like this :

```
Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);
Message message = new Message.Builder()
    .addData("message", "this is the message")
    .addData("other-parameter", "some value")
    .build();
Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, numOfRetries);
```

Comment: How can I set if it's for test or production by configuring ip/port and so on?

Comment: @handicop I'm not sure what you are asking. GCM has no distinction between test and production (unlike Apple Push Notifications). The Sender class is hard coded to send the request to the GCM HTTP endpoint url.

Comment: I see. I am currently looking at GCM CCS(XMPP), where I can configure the end point. For CCS, I guess I should not use the gcm-server.jar or Sender class, instead, I guess I should be looking at  GoogleCloudMessaging APIs.

Comment: How to keep running to listen the upstream message?

Comment: I didn't find gcm-server.jar on the given link but found in Maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gcm/gcm-server/1.0.0

Answer (score -1):

I would like to share a more better approach which confirms message delivered successfully or not. We can do this using `RestTemplate` and `HTTPPost`.

I will show how we can do it using `gcm.jar`

```
public class GCMJarGCM {
    public static final String GCM_API_KEY = "Get this API key from Google Developer Console";
    public static final String MESSAGE_VALUE = "Hello, Sending Notifications using GCM";    
    public static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";
    public static final String REG_ID = "This you'll get once you register on GCM";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Sender sender = new Sender(GCM_API_KEY);

        ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        devicesList.add(REG_ID);

        Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, MESSAGE_VALUE).build();

        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
        sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

The output you'll see like below:

```
MulticastResult(multicast_id=4951949299732552396,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1445408305351488%2a748ce7f9fd7ecd ]]
```

If you want to use HTTPPost or RestTemplate then you need to use EndPoint: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send