# Is PHP necessary to implement GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement android push notification by using GCM. But, in all the tutorials that I have referred so far, I get one or more PHP files. Is it not possible without PHP, because I don't know PHP. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I f you want to implement GCM you'll need a mediator file php/.net etc which acts as communicator between your server and the GCM server.This file pass the message to be delivered along with the projectid(registered with google console)to GCM server.So that GCM server can send push messages to all mobile devices regisytered under the corrosponding projectid.You can use this based on your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have PHP for GCM, you can use any server side language i.e. Java (J2EE), Python, etc. But what you must have is a server.

See what android is saying about GCM [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

> A full GCM implementation requires both a client implementation and a
>   server implementation. For more information about implementing the
>   server side, see [Implementing GCM Server](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html).

Some similar questions:

[GCM java server example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261024/gcm-java-server-example)

[How to send notification to Android app from Java server using GCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758402/how-to-send-notification-to-android-app-from-java-server-using-gcm)