# GCM implementation in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Am new to android .I want to implement `push notification` from server side to client side using `GCM`. I found `GCM` is the best to implement my job.But Unfortunately my work has stuck due to some doubts and errors.

- I used gcmquickstart code for client implementaion using client
  documentation.But i didn't get proper output its showing only a token
  retriving in progress for a long time.
- For integrating server and client code in one project.Are they
  implemented as 2 different activities in the same project or 2
  different directories.
- What is the purpose of using Google app engine. I want all codes to
  be in android java implementation

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** You can get all you need from:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Trust me, I implemented GCM Android example app by Android studio yesterday.

Note that in step 2, press **GET A CONFIGURATION FILE** to get your own sender ID setting file, and copy that into the /app folder. By this procedure, Google will automatically generate server key and enable GCM api.

**Question 2:** I'm not sure what you really want, but it is possible. (But it is weird.) You can use HTTPRequest to send GCM message. That means, your Android app can be both GCM sender(app) and GCM receiver(app).

I will not show you how to sending GCM here, but if you want to test sending GCM, there is very easy way.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
Send a message using GCM HTTP connection server protocol:

```
  https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
  Content-Type:application/json
  Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
  {
    "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
    "data": {
      "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
     }
  }
```

To do this, you can use chrome plugin, POSTMAN.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-short/mkhojklkhkdaghjjfdnphfphiaiohkef?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

And, type URL, header, body like following image.
[image]

**Question 3:** you can get GCM server example from here:
[GCM java server example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261024/gcm-java-server-example)